# "Catastrophic failure" on MapControl tap with Windows Phone 10 SDK

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm displaying a MapControl inside a Windows 10 application.

It's perfectly working on Windows 10 Desktop, but I get a weird "Catastrophic failure" exception with the Windows 10 Phone emulator if I tap the map.

[image: Exception]

**Edit**: I discovered something interesting. If I click on a different control (a Button or whatever), BEFORE I tap the map => No problem. 
However, if I start the app and I firstly tap the map on Windows Phone => Crash. Weird!

**Edit 2**: I checked with the official sample from Microsoft, same thing! By default, the UI forces you to touch a split button to show the map. I changed the code to directly show the map at launch, and if I tap the map: BOOM. It crashes.

Comment: What does your XAML and C# code look like? Do you have some event handlers attached? Is the Bing Maps API key correct?

Comment: Is the component initially collapsed? As far as I can remember, this is what was causing this error in my 8.1 uwp. This is also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214664/adding-mapcontrol-in-xaml-results-in-a-catastropic-failure

Comment: @sibbl Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/bbougot/21658d598eab122138ee
Yes, my Bing Maps API key is correct.
I've checked it but the component is visible. The issue randomly occurs when I tap the map as soon as the MapControl is fully loaded. Sometimes it works, sometimes is doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem not solved, but I discovered a bug with MapControl.

Use case:

- Create a UWP app targeting Windows 10.
- Inside the MainPage, put a MapControl
- Start the app on Windows Phone
- Tap the Map
- Boom.

Protip: Place a control in the MainPage (like a Button). Then, if you focus this control then you tap the map, it's ok. The problem occurs if you tap the map prior focusing no other control.

Edit: Problem solved with Windows 10 build 10565.